# if,else statement within a for loop in R error

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I apologize for the bit of a mess of code but I am relatively new to R and when I input the following code:

```
for(t in 2:M)
{
alphcandidate=mvrnorm(1,Gibbsalph[,t-1],as.numeric(csquared*4.93)*Zyesinv)

r=exp((-1/2)*(t(rep(1,105))%*%Z%*%(alphacandidate-Gibbsalph[,t-1])+sum((lnyield-X%*%Gibbsbeta[,t-1])^2)%*%(exp(-Z%*%alphcandidate)-exp(-Z%*%Gibbsalph[,t-1]))+t(alphcandidate-rep(0,m))%*%(solve(as.numeric(100)*diag(m)))%*%(alphcandidate-rep(0,m))-t(Gibbsalph[,t-1]-rep(0,m))%*%(solve(as.numeric(100)*diag(m)))%*%(Gibbsalph[,t-1]-rep(0,m)))

if(runif(1)<min(1,r)) {
Gibbsalph[,t]=alphcandidate
} else{
Gibbsalph[,t]=Gibbsalph[,t-1]
}

Dbetanawinv=t(X)%*%(diag(as.vector(1/(exp(Z%*%Gibbsalph[,t])))))%*%X+solve(as.numeric(100)*diag(n))
Dbetach=chol(Dbetanawinv)
Dbetachinv=solve(Dbetach)
Dbeta=Dbetachinv%*%t(Dbetachinv)
dbeta=t(X)%*%(diag(as.vector(1/(exp(Z%*%Gibbsalph[,t])))))%*%lnyield+(solve(as.numeric(100)*diag(n))%*%(rep(0,n)))  
     Gibbsbeta[,t]=mvrnorm(1,Dbeta%*%dbeta,Dbeta)
}
```

I get the following errors:
Error: unexpected 'if' in:
"if"

Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

I'm not sure why this if statement is not working properly. Sorry as I do not yet know how to format my question properly on this website either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should to indent your code better, also break up long statements so the code becomes more readable. Such errors are usually solvable by just formatting the code better.

Comment: Or an IDE. I use Eclipse that signals which line has a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `)` at the end (?) of the line `r = exp(...`

Pasting into RStudio shows this with the indent level:

```
  r=exp((-1/2)*(t(rep(1,105))%*%Z%*%(alphacandidate-Gibbsalph[,t-1])+sum((lnyield-X%*%Gibbsbeta[,t-1])^2)%*%(exp(-Z%*%alphcandidate)-exp(-Z%*%Gibbsalph[,t-1]))+t(alphcandidate-rep(0,m))%*%(solve(as.numeric(100)*diag(m)))%*%(alphcandidate-rep(0,m))-t(Gibbsalph[,t-1]-rep(0,m))%*%(solve(as.numeric(100)*diag(m)))%*%(Gibbsalph[,t-1]-rep(0,m)))

        if(runif(1)<min(1,r)) {
          Gibbsalph[,t]=alphcandidate
```